# What to pass command line argument in running exe. having multiple instance running with same exe name

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I am making a window service which will trigger at specific time to start/run an .exe. There are many instance running depend on trigger event
Example
**

```
1. Trigger A fire at morning and start/run controller.EXE
2. Trigger B fire at Afternoon and start/run controller.EXE
```

**
**EDIT**

I have used below

```
                Process A = new Process();
                A.StartInfo.FileName = @"Controller.exe"; 
                A.StartInfo.Arguments = strXML+" "+strEndDate;
                A.Start();

                Process B = new Process();
                B.StartInfo.FileName = @"Controller.exe"; 
                B.StartInfo.Arguments = strXML+" "+strEndDate;
                B.Start();
```

Now A and B both are running. I want to pass command line argument to process A while it is running

How can I achieve that. Is that possible with multiple exe having same name(controller.EXE)?[image]

Comment: Did you already set up a communication method with a single instance of controller.exe ?

Comment: If you want to start "controller.exe" with parameters, you could use ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) with arguments.

Comment: @Graffito No, controller .exe is window application. Can I use Mutex? If yes than how can I for that? what I have to pass in command line argument?

Comment: Windows provides many means to communicate between processes. refer to [InterProcess communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx). A possible solution is the [MailSlots](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623268/Csharp-wrapper-for-Mailslots). As you may have many instance of "Controller.exe", You should give to each instance of the "controller.exe" a different mailslot name provided in the command line. Theen, your process may communicate to either A or B by writing on the appropriate mailslot.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question:

> Is that possible with multiple exe having same name(controller.EXE)

Yes, sure. Look at Windows Task Manager in Process tab and you will see a lot of processes running with the same name. For instance, every tab in Chrome browser is running in its own process

[image].

About this

> What to pass command line argument in running exe

You can pass any parameters you need or nothing. It depends on your application logic.